# Open source implementations of Symmetric Searchable Encryption and Order Preserving Encryption

Tags: symmetric, order-preserving, cryptdb

Are there open source implementations of SSE and OPE?
Can anyone please point to sample codes, if available.

**EDIT**

If cryptDB is not an option, what other options are available?
(Indeed, these schemes are weak — which is why cryptDB proposes onion layers for encryption.)

Comment: 1) These kinds of encryption are inherently weak 2) Take a look at [CryptDB](http://css.csail.mit.edu/cryptdb)

Comment: Understand the design of these schemes and implement them :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reference implementations and software recommendations

Comment: I have extracted the OPE code from cryptoDB: https://github.com/hilder-vitor/ope-from-cryptodb  It makes it easier to use this scheme, because we don't need to encrypt the whole cryptoDB. And also, I've made a Makefile and a simple example to make it more friendly.

Answer (score 4):

[cryptdb](http://css.csail.mit.edu/cryptdb/) has these implementations inside it . But their licensing is not Open sources as in GPL etc . They say its available for research purposes !

I have implemented [Symmetric Searchable Encryption in Java](https://github.com/sashank/jsse), its LGPL

Comment: In fact, the LICENSE file that comes with the cryptdb's source code says that the software is under GPL v3.